# Как организовать взаимодействие классов между собой

Tags: c++, qt, классы, указатели, ui

Задача: Есть главное окно (класс MainWindow), по нажатию кнопки создается диалоговое модальное окно с вариантами "Ок" и "Отмена" (класс Dialog).

Суть задачи в том, чтобы по нажатию кнопки ок создавалась новая кнопка на Главном Окне. Именно создавалась новая, а не показывалась скрытая и т.п. Нашел интересное решение через создание "класса динамический кнопки" (QDynamicButton) и там при нажатии кнопки создавался новый объект класса QDynamicButton (и соответственно кнопка).

Все это отлично работало, пока сама кнопка и слот, к которому была подключена кнопка, стояли в mainwindow. И как только я захотел перенести этот функционал в класс Dialog и привязать к кнопке Ок диалогового окна начались проблемы.

Код dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "qdynamicbutton.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QDynamicButton *button = new QDynamicButton(this);
    button->setText("Кнопочка " + QString::number(button->getID()));
    MainWindow::ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(button);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotGetNumber()));
}
```

Конкретно в этом случае пытался сделать эту функцию дружественной и получить доступ к `ui` класса MainWindow. Получаю ошибку:

> invalid use of non-static data member `ui`.

Что я пробовал и какие решения находил:

- Сделать MainWindow::ui приват или протектед - я так понял это костыли и нарушается инкапсуляция (если я не прав - поправьте).
- Описать функцию в mainwindow.cpp и в dialog.cpp попытаться к ней обратиться вот так

```
void Dialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(); // еще пробовал добавить void вначале
}
```

Ошибка:

> call to non-static member function without an object argument.

- Через создание объекта класса MainWindow и подключение сигнала-слота (это наверное вообще бред был)

Еще что-то пробовал, но везде результат один: либо неправильная передача данных в функцию, либо нет доступа к объекту класса.

Подскажите, как правильно архитектурно и "синтаксисно" сделать данный функционал? И где можно нормально найти инфу про использование указателей/динамической памяти (в реалиях работы с Qt, а не консольные передачи по указателям интов "в вакууме").

Comment: @Bogdan Запускается главное окно (MainWindow), жмется кнопочка "Добавить" - вызывается модальное окно (Dialog) с выбором "Ок" и "Отмена". По кнопке "Ок" должна была создаваться динамическая кнопка на MainWindow.

Comment: `Через создание объекта класса MainWindow и подключение сигнала-слота (это наверное вообще бред был)` - ну да, ключевая фишка всего UI в Qt именно что бред. Заведите в своём MainWindow метод или `slot` `addButton()`. Если это метод - отдавай в ваш диалог указатель на объект mainWindow и вызывайте в обработчике `ok` метод `addButton`. Хотя вы и так наверное отдаёте в диалог указатель на MainWindow в виде `QWidget* parent`, вам тогда просто `parent()` кастануть к вашему `MainWindow` с помощью `qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent())` понадобится. Со слотом - сделайте сигнал у диалога.

Comment: Относительно вашей ошибки. Вы неверно обращаетесь к полю `ui` класса `MainWindow`. Указанным вами способом можно обращаться лишь к **статическим** полям класса, о чем вам и говорит компилятор. Для обращения к нестатическим полям класса, нужно иметь доступ к **экземпляру** этого класса, которого у вас и нет. Но в любом случае этот подход имеет слишком большую связность и вам лучше использовать вариант @bogdan.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо вам, Bogdan!
Проанализировав ваш код и сопоставив с моим добился нужного результата.
Заработала следующая конструкция:

```
void MainWindow::on_addButton_clicked() // Нажимаем кнопку "Добавить"
{
    Dialog NewTheme;
    NewTheme.setModal(true); // Создаем модальное окно
    //NewTheme.exec();
    if (NewTheme.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)  // Нажатие кнопки "Ок"
    {
        /*создание новой кнопки*/
        QDynamicButton *button = new QDynamicButton(this);
        button->setText("Кнопочка " + QString::number(button->getID()));
        ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(button);
        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotGetNumber()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В текущей ситуации классы ссылаются друг на друга. Они слишком много знают друг о друге и это не есть хорошо. При организации взаимодействия классов следует избегать двунаправленных связей.

Я бы организовал желаемое взаимодействие с помощью метода [QDialog::exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec). Картина примерно следующая:

1. При запуске этого метода MainWindow приостанавливается.
2. Возвращается специальное значение.
3. Объект MainWindow в зависимости от этого значения сам делает то, что нужно.

Кодом выглядит как-то так:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonAdd_clicked()
{
    Dialog dialog;
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        // ... делаем что нужно
    }
}
```

В итоге имеем:

1. Никаких лишних костылей в виде создания дополнительных окон, дополнительных методов или сигналов/слотов.
2. Dialog ничего не знает про MainWindow (что в свою очередь хорошо: представьте, что завтра надо будет перенести функциональность еще куда-то. В этом случае Dialog останется нетронутым).

Если же для создания доп. кнопки нужны еще какие-то данные из диалога, то можно добавить дополнительный сигнал в Dialog, который параметром передает соответствующие данные, а в MainWindow слотом ловить этот сигнал. Тут уже без сигналов/слотов не обойтись. Но тем не менее, связь классов останется односторонней.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но он не решает проблему.
Я создал по вашему коду метод в mainwindow.cpp. Вы там указали "делаем то что нужно", т е мне нужно создать кнопку. Ок, но тут мы работает внутри функции класса Dialog и я опять упираюсь в невозможность использования строки ``` ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(button); ``` потому что не получается из класса Dialog манипулировать с MainWindow::ui. 
Я так понимаю мне надо зафиксировать нажатие кнопки в диалоговом окне и как-то это передать в mainwindow типа "триггера", что бы там сработала функция, описанная в void Dialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()

Comment: @sanyalitv, извиняюсь, я опечатался. Это все делается в MainWindow. Я исправил в примере кода. В результате все действия будут происходить в MainWindow. И проблем с "невозможностью использования" не будет.